# what is wrong with my nginx.conf file. rewrite issues

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I am new to nginx and I have been hacking up my nginx.conf file to get a site working but still having issues with a few different things. Here is the scope and some problems. #2 below is most important. My nginx.conf file is located at the bottom via pastebin link.

1) my site has vanity urls... domain.com/username (this works)

2) my site also has directories in root.  domain.com/red/ but the cannot be viewed because the following comes up... (This is a 404 error, page cannot be found.) I would like domain.com/red/ to just show up

3) I also have a wp blog and it is located here: domain.com/blog/ redirects to www.domain.com/blog/ (It shows up and works but I prefer to not have 'www.' Also can't use seo friendly permalink urls)

Here is my [nginx.conf file](http://pastebin.com/HDcH2PZ8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `try_files` statement for the directory.

Check [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) for more info on it.

Also we need the site specific configuration file, in addition to your `nginx.conf`

Comment: thanks, what is the 'site specific configuration file... where is it located and whats the name of file?

Comment: @Andrew - It's located in different area's per distro, and per your install.  Try checking in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

Comment: perhaps its virtual.conf? found in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ http://pastebin.com/30iSspvi   thx again for helping me.

Comment: @Andrew - It might be, it all depends on how you installed and setup nginx.  I cant really tell you which configuration file you are using for your website.  Just know that there is a conf file for your site and that is where you need to set this stuff up at.